# get element attribute value in span of second div

Tags: html, jquery, attributes

I have created a loop in order to get all fields "names" with attribute "my-data".
In the example below my-data has values "MYFIELD_1" and "MYFIELD_2".

```
<div class="my-col">
    <div class="label">This is my field</div>
    <div class="label-text ">
        <span my-data="MYFIELD_1"/></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="my-col">
    <div class="label">This is my field</div>
    <div class="label-text ">
        <span my-data="MYFIELD_2"/></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
$(".label").each(function() {
    var fieldLabel =  $(this).find("div:eq(2)").closest("span").attr("my-data");
    console.log("field label : "+ fieldLabel) ;
}
```

result returns undefined

As a jquery beginner it really is painful and your help will make me happy ;)

Thanks

Jacques

Answer (score 0):

Your code is along the right lines, but there's a few issues:

- The `.label` elements don't contain any `div` elements so `find('div:eq(2)')` won't find anything.
- Assuming `.label` is supposed to be `.my-col` instead, then as indexes are zero-based the selector should be `:eq(1)`.
- `closest('span')` needs to be `find('span')` instead, as `closest()` goes up the DOM, not down it.
- Don't create non-standard attributes such as `my-data`. Use `data` attributes to include your own meta data with an element
- `span` elements aren't self closing, so the `/>` needs to just be `>`.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(".my-col").each(function() {
  var fieldLabel = $(this).find("div:eq(1) span").data("my-data");
  console.log("field label : " + fieldLabel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-col">
  <div class="label">This is my field</div>
  <div class="label-text">
    <span data-my-data="MYFIELD_1"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my-col">
  <div class="label">This is my field</div>
  <div class="label-text">
    <span data-my-data="MYFIELD_2"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also want to consider targeting `.label-text` directly instead of using `:eq()`, as the latter can be broken quite easily by a simple HTML change.

Comment: Great thank you Rory, you saved my day.
Your explanations are great!!
Cheers
JT.

Comment: No problem, glad to help